# Do I need a separate IP address per subnet for every database in a Basic Availability Group?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, sql-server-2016

I have a pair of SQL Servers running in two different subnets (in AWS if that matters) and a couple of databases that I want to run in a Basic Availability Group.

My understanding is that in SQL Server 2016 Standard I need a separate Availability Group for every database. Also at least in the user interface it looks like an AG Listener can only belong to a single Availability Group.

I get errors when I try to reuse the IP address for another AG listener (i.e. use 10.0.0.1 and 10.0.1.1 for AG listeners LISTENER1 and LISTENER2)

Do I really need to create a separate AG Listener with two unique IP addresses for every AG and thus every database, or is there a way to reuse either the IP addresses or the AG listeners?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do I really need to create a separate AG Listener with two unique IP addresses >for every AG and thus every database, or is there a way to reuse either the IP >addresses or the AG listeners?

Yes, really, you do.

In fact, you'll need a unique IP address for each listener for each subnet that listener could potentially live in. Why? Well it's not very helpful to have a listener that can't listen. This is true whether Basic AGs are used or not.

Comment: On Enterprise I could, of course, just put all the databases in the same AG. I am wondering if there is a similar solution for Basic AGs as well.

Comment: @hrnt Unfortunately, there is not as each BAG could technically be on different instances. If you're a glutton for punishment, use a single listener for a single BAG and then write your own logic to make sure all BAGs are hosted on the same instance.. ALWAYS.. then technically you could use a single listener... but I wouldn't want to support that.

Comment: There is actually a workaround for this. You can use a database mirroring connection string (Failover Partner), which lets you connect to a BAG without setting up an availability group listener.